# Does the Exchange Control Panel allow standard users to log in and make changes to mailboxes that they have permissions over?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007

Does the Exchange Control Panel (ECP) included with Exchange Server 2010 allow standard users (i.e. Active Directory objects that don't include any Exchange security groups) to log into the ECP and make changes to mailboxes that are either associated with their Active Directory object, or mailboxes where Full Access permissions have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment, I create a user mailbox, an ordinary user, without any permissions, not in any group. I logon ECP, I see this, screenshot for your reference: What you can change is almost what you can change on outlook client.[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Apologies - I'm totally blind and use a screen reader which isn't able to read the text of your screenshot - is the option to add an out-of-office present on that screen?

Comment: Yes. You can configure OOF. But you can also set OOF in OWA without necessarily logging into ECP.
In other words, the ECP where ordinary users log in actually correspond to the Options in the OWA.